# Add a submodule which can't be removed from the index

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to add a submodule that already existed (different git remote repository). As I didn't searched before how to do it correctly, I think I've messed up my repository and I need some help to fix it again.

I've already deleted all the relevant sections from the .gitmodules and .git/config regarding the submodules I want to delete. I've also verified that there is not modules directory inside my .git/ directory.

However, when I run the command `git rm --cached path_to_submodule`, the following message is displayed:

```
fatal: pathspec 'path_to_submodule' did not match any files
```

As the previous command fails, when I try to add again the same submodule with the new definitions, running the command `git submodule add gituser@host:repo.git`, this is the displayed message:

```
'repo' already exists in the index
```

Comment: I was trying to add a submodule with the same name of an already existing file in the index.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The only way that message (`'repo' already exists in the index`) can be displayed is if 'repo' still exists in the index (see [this chapter on submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)):

```
$ rm -Rf rack/
$ git submodule add git@github.com:schacon/rack.git rack
'rack' already exists in the index

You have to unstage the rack directory first. Then you can add the submodule:

$ git rm -r rack
$ git submodule add git@github.com:schacon/rack.git rack
```

Even if '`rack`' isn't a submodule, if it exists, it would prevent the declaration of a submodule of the same name.

Answer (score 14):

If the output adding a new submodule is:

```
'FolderName' already exists in the index
```

Tip the next commands

```
git ls-files --stage
```

The output will be something similar to:

```
160000 d023657a21c1bf05d0eeaac6218eb5cca8520d16  0  FolderName
```

Then, to remove the folder index tip:

```
git rm -r --cached FolderName
```

Try again add the submodule

Comment: "git rm -r --cached" is the key to fix the conflict issue for the existing submodule already registered in the index tree but couldn't be gotten thru git add that submodule

Answer (score 4):

May occur, when merging with error, manual deleting of folder of submodule, or something else, like Hallileo Comet

1. in file `.gitmodules` - delete links to submodule (whole section with submodule name)
2. in file `.git\config` - delete links to submodule, as in previous step
3. in folder `.git\modules` - delete folder with relative path similar to relative path of "problem" module
4. ensure, that folder of submodule is not exists anymore
5. then:

   `$ git submodule add -f --name <name> <git://path_1.git> <path_2>`

   where: name - name of submodule as u wish, may be equal your `repo` name;    - path to submodule source repo (ie - github, etc),  - relative path to folder where submodule will reside

   this lets u to add submodule within path or with name which still present in index, but not naturally alive.

i didn't found any method to remove these dead links from index, but when forced

Answer (score 1):

'submodules/uasdk-clib' already exists in the index

git rm -r --cached submodules/uasdk-clib

git submodule add -b china/release/16.8.0 -f ssh://git@xxx-ios-uasdk.git submodules/uasdk-clib

Answer (score 1):

this is because you have the folder in your repo same name as the name of your submodule

```
$ git rm -r subModuleName
$ git submodule add "your submodule repo path without these quotes"
```

Try again adding the submodule

Answer (score 0):

If you have otherwise completely removed a submodule, and are trying to add it back in again, but you're getting an error that it already exists in the index......

```
git update-index --remove path_to_submodule
```

...to remove it from the index.  You should then be able to add the submodule again.